# How to use Haar Feature results in Viola Jones Face Detection Algorithm

Tags: algorithm, adaboost, haar-wavelet, viola-jones

I am trying to understand the Viola-jones Face detection algorithm. In paper they have mentioned that there can be 160k plus haar features in a 24x24 pxiels image.

I am struggling in understanding how to determine the weak classifier. For example If I have 10k images, faces + non-faces. I swap one Haar feature over the entire set of images. Now since the result of a feature is an integer value(difference between the sum of white area and the gray area) how can we use this integer value to determine whether it has correctly classified a face or a non-face image.

Thanks
Ali Umair

Answer (score 1):

For each Haar-like feature, there is a threshold which indicates accept or reject.  For example, the threshold may say that the difference between the dark and light areas must be greater than 10 for it to be possible that a face exists at this location.

The Haar-like features are at a very low level of the detection.  They only help you quickly eliminate possibilities.  You have to train the system as to which Haar-like features are the most useful in deciding whether a face might be present. If you have a Haar-like feature that fails, and that failure tells you that a face is very likely not present at the current location, you can then proceed to the next location without having to check all the other Haar-like features at the current location.

Comment: Good explanation. Also worth noting that HAAR strength is in the inherent parallelism. Here's a nice presentation about this (I just love that link, guess why :) - http://download.intel.com/il/General/1525%20Yaki%20A%20guide%20to%20AMDs%20Heterogeneous%20System%20Architecture.pdf

Comment: Ok but what i was trying to find is that how do we know that a Haar feature is failed to detect a face. The result of a feature is an integer value obtained by taking difference between the sum of black and the sum of white area. On the basis of this single value how can we determine that this feature didn't find face

Comment: @user2793078: For each used feature, there is a corresponding threshold.  I've added some detail to my answer.

Comment: Thanks Vaughn Cato. Is there a 'standard' threshold value corresponding to each Haar location or how do we determine the good threshold value for each of 160k haar features.

Comment: @user2793078: Yes, in the paper they say that each weak classifier consists of a feature, a threshold, and a parity.